# How to pass the SSL config like truststore location and password?

Tags: node.js, ssl, apache-kafka

Right now I have configured my Kafka server with a self-signed certificate.

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    hostname: zookeeper
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.11-2.0.0
    command: [start-kafka.sh]
    ports:
      - 9093:9093
    hostname: kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: SSL://0.0.0.0:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: SSL://alfrescokafka.leafycode.com:9093
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION: /home/amur42s/ssl/kafka.server.keystore.jks
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: oE4KJ9FVMjMXGpgpp0qwLzUDy0uz
      KAFKA_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD: oE4KJ9FVMjMXGpgpp0qwLzUDy0uz
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: /home/amur42s/ssl/kafka.server.truststore.jks
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: 123
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 116.203.65.132 # docker-machine ip
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: ""
      KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH: 'required'
      KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: 'SSL'
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /home/ssl:/home/ssl
    depends_on:
      - "zookeeper"
```

Unfortunately, I'm unable to connect to it using Kafka-node `TimeoutError: Request timed out after 30000ms`. Looks like I need to set the `ssl.truststore.location` and `ssl.trsutstore.password`. How can I do this?

```
export const kafkaClientOptions = {
  kafkaHost: process.env.KAFKA_PRODUCER_HOST,
  ssl: true,
  sslOptions: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
};

const client = new kafka.KafkaClient(kafkaClientOptions);

const Producer = kafka.Producer;
const producer = new Producer(client);
```

Comment: Maybe you should show your node code and the errors you're getting? `KafkaClient` takes `sslOptions`... https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node

Comment: Define 'unable to connect'.

Comment: SSL configuration would not cause a 30 second request timeout. It would cause a handshake failure, pretty quickly.

Comment: @user207421I get a timeout error `TimeoutError: Request timed out after 30000ms`.

Answer (score 3):

you shouldn't get timeout error because of SSL miss-configuration, but here are the configs to setup Kafka client with SSL

```
ssl:true,
sslOptions: {
    key: fileManager.readFile("path/to/key"),
    cert: fileManager.readFile("path/to/cert"),
    ca: fileManager.readFile("path/to/ca"),
    passphrase: "your_passphrase"
}
```

Comment: Which answer is this? He's asking for truststore location and password!

Comment: @alessandroAmedei And that is what this does. It sets the passphrase and reads the files from those locations